# Insert background image in search page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple search bar, similar to Amazon's with a background image covering the whole webpage. Somehow the image is not shown with my code. Any idea why?
I have tried to insert the image from a relative path in my directory but still it is not working. Does it have anything to do with the use of bootstrap? I removed the bootstrap reference but still the same problem occured.

```css
body {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("background_search.jpg");
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

select {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

button {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.input-group-addon {
  padding: 0!important;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.allElements {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 10em;
  margin-top: 15em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="css/mainCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="allElements">
      <h1>NotaryPedia</h1>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
     <select>
    <option>All</option>
    <option>Author</option>
    <option>Date</option>
    <option>Person</option>
    <option>Place</option>
    <option>Reference</option>
    <option>Subject</option>
     </select>
    </span>

          <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Enter search..." />

          <span class="input-group-addon"> <button>Submit</button></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide us with directory structure and complete css code (we don't know which element you are trying to style and set background-image of).

Comment: Where's the image file? Paths in CSS file are relative to that file (not HTML it's linked in), so the browser is looking for `css/background_search.jpg`…

Comment: probably it's the path to the file that is not correct. As previous comments suggest could you just give a bit of hint on how the assets structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

You missed background-size: cover; to fill the image. Also, you need to keep image in reachable location (*in the relative path or exposed over http*)

```
body {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("background_search.jpg");
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Still didn't work with background-size: cover. The image is in the same folder as the html file to make sure that I am not making any mistakes in the path

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css

```
body {
background: url('background_search.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50% fixed;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by giving the whole relative path